# Command Cooldown for a Python Twitch Bot

Tags: python, bots, twitch

I'm making a Twitch Bot using Pthon. I want to create a cooldown on the commands so you can only call the command once every (x) seconds. 
Eg:

```
Rustie: test
Bot: Testing command
*Imediately after*
Rustie: test
*5 seconds later*
Rustie: test
Bot: Testing command
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work (Also I want to get rid of time.sleep as during that time I can't use other commands):

```
used = []
if "test" in message:
    if "test" in used:
        time.sleep(5)
        del(used[:])
    else:
        sendMessage(s, "Testing command")
        used.append("test")

    break
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the time passed since the last invocation of each command. You can do it with the `time` module.

```
import time

min_call_freq = 5
used = {}

def call_command(command):
    print('Calling command `%s`.' % command)
    # do whatever

def cooldown(command):
    print('You have used command `%s` in the last %u seconds.' % (command, min_call_freq))

def process_command(command):
    if (
        command not in used or
        time.time() - used[command] > min_call_freq
    ):
        used[command] = time.time()
        call_command(command)
    else:
        cooldown(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to restructure your code to use modular `MessageHandler` classes that can each handle a particular type of message (i.e. have a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), with the bot's overall behaviour being determined by the type and order of these message handlers within a [chain of responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility):

[image]

Among several other benefits, this **makes it easy to implement cooldowns between command invocations** (in the implementation below, you can customise different duration cooldowns for different types of message).

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep


class MessageHandler(ABC):
    def __init__(self, command_cooldown):
        self._command_cooldown = command_cooldown
        self._last_command_usage = datetime.min

    def try_handle_message(self, message):
        if self._can_handle_message(message) and not self.__on_cooldown:
            self._last_command_usage = datetime.now()
            return self._handle_message(message)
        else:
            return None

    @property
    def __on_cooldown(self):
        return datetime.now() - self._last_command_usage <= self._command_cooldown

    @abstractmethod
    def _can_handle_message(self, s):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _handle_message(self, s):
        pass


class TestMessageHandler(MessageHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timedelta(seconds=5))

    def _can_handle_message(self, s):
        return 'test' in s

    def _handle_message(self, s):
        return 'Testing command'


class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._message_handlers = [TestMessageHandler()]

    def receive_message(self, message):
        print('Received:', message)
        for message_handler in self._message_handlers:
            response = message_handler.try_handle_message(message)
            if response:
                self.send_response(response)

    def send_response(self, response):
        print('Responding:', response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = Bot()
    bot.receive_message('test')

    for i in range(6):
        bot.receive_message('test')
        print('Sleep 1 second...')
        sleep(1)
```

**Output**

```
Received: test
Responding: Testing command
Received: test
Sleep 1 second...
Received: test
Sleep 1 second...
Received: test
Sleep 1 second...
Received: test
Sleep 1 second...
Received: test
Sleep 1 second...
Received: test
Responding: Testing command
Sleep 1 second...
```