# Better way to parse input from string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm making a bot that will output different information depending on the user input (a string). I'm wondering if there is a better way to parse the input and redirect to different outcomes:

```
def query(msg: str):
    if re.compile(r"moci(o|ó)?n(es)? de (procedimiento)s?", re.IGNORECASE).search(msg):
        return open("mociones/mocion_procedimiento.txt", "r").read()

    elif re.compile(r"moci(o|ó)?n(es)? de (ó|o)?rden(es)?", re.IGNORECASE).search(msg):
        return open("mociones/mocion_orden.txt", "r").read()

    elif re.compile(r"moci(o|ó)?n(es)? de duda(s)?", re.IGNORECASE).search(msg):
        return open("mociones/mocion_duda.txt", "r").read()

    elif re.compile(r"moci(o|ó)?n(es)? de privilegio(s)?", re.IGNORECASE).search(msg):
        return open("mociones/mocion_privilegio.txt", "r").read()

    ...

    elif re.compile(r"defender (el|los)? anteproyectos?", re.IGNORECASE).search(msg):
        return open("debate_particular/index.txt", "r").read()

    elif re.compile(r"anteproyectos?", re.IGNORECASE).search(msg):
        return open("anteproyecto/index.txt", "r").read()

    else:
        return "_*ERROR*_\n\nNo search results were found for \n`{query}`".format(query=msg)
```

Comment: *"Better"* how? If this is working code you think could be improved, look into [codereview.se]. Also, note that by explicitly re-compiling the regexes every time you call the function it's probably less efficient, if anything, than not compiling them at all; to benefit from the compilation, move it *outside* the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious suggestion would be to have a dict `regex => path` and use a loop instead of a bunch of `if` statements:

```
paths = {
    r"(?i)moci[oó]?n(es)? de (procedimiento)s?": "mociones/mocion_procedimiento.txt",
    r"(?i)moci[oó]?n(es)? de [óo]?rden(es)?": "mociones/mocion_orden.txt"
}

def path_for_msg(msg):
    for r, p in paths.items():
        if re.search(r, msg):
            return p
```

Also `re.compile` is hardly if ever needed, because `re` takes care of compiling behind the scenes.

If the order is important, then the proper data structure is a list of tuples:

```
paths = [
    (r"(?i)moci[oó]?n(es)? de (procedimiento)s?", "mociones/mocion_procedimiento.txt"),
    (r"(?i)moci[oó]?n(es)? de [óo]?rden(es)?", "mociones/mocion_orden.txt")
}

def path_for_msg(msg):
    for r, p in paths:
        if re.search(r, msg):
            return p
```

Comment: But is there a way I can mantain the order? This seems to be ignoring it at all... Order is important

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to adopt a more object-oriented approach, creating separate classes to handle different types of inputs and arranging them into a chain of responsibility - similar to georg's suggestion except you'd be iterating over *message handler objects* instead of raw regex patterns.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41902552/1636276) for more details.